# How to find a word containing bracket "(" and using word boundaries?

Tags: java, regex, word-boundaries

I am looking for a phrase "**in successes (and learn from their failures!)**" in a big text. Since there are brackets i have used quote(...) to allow it, but i also want to use word boundaries "\b" so this phrase will be ignored if it was found in such text "Kin successes (and learn from their failures!)".

Here is my code :

```
String phrase = Pattern.quote( "in successes (and learn from their failures!)" );   
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile( "\\b" + phrase + "\\b" );  // Use word boundary(\b) = No letters after it.
Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher( bigText );
myMatcher.find();  // Returns false.
```

As mentioned this code will return false because of using "\b". If i omitted "\b" the matcher will return true. **Is there a way to fix this while using the 2 conditions: quote(...) + "\b" ?**

Comment: Shouldn't you be escaping the braces -- `phrase.replace("(", "\\(")`

Comment: @Nishan: It is not only braces. It may be /\*^$#_- or any other character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option here in my opinion is to drop the second `\b`:

```
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile( "\\b" + phrase);
```

`phrase` ends with `!)`, which aren't word characters, and should match well for all cases, for example: `failures!), and more`, `failures!)`, `failures!)or not`

If you want to make sure it isn't followed by another letter you can use `"\\b" + phrase + "\\B"`, but I'm not sure it's needed here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but my question is general. I have many words and phrases to look for, so i do not want the above phrase to also fetch "in successes (and learn from their failures!)done" for example. I hope you get the idea here. It is not about this phrase exactly.

Comment: @Brad - you can check - if the phrase starts with a `^\b`, add a `"\\b"` to it, and add a `"\\B"` otherwise, and the same for `\b$`. It should get you what you want, I I understand correctly.

Comment: Sorry ... I do not get your idea here. Can you please edit your entry to translate this to code ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have understood what you meant, and it worked fine.